# How to fix overlap issue on wordpress website

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, mobile-website

I am using WordPress and have a problem with overlap between the sentences of body and blog sidebar.

But it just happens on mobile phone with the small screen size (4-5 inches) only, laptop or tablet is ok. How do I separate them to display better and avoid overlap issues?

This is the information of issue: Theme WordPress: Organic food theme
    Link issue: [Link of my website, that has this issue on mobile](http://quanglepro.com/category/seo/)

[image file of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8urIq.png)

Please help me with this. Nice day, Quanglepro

Comment: can you check my answer please

Comment: there is no issue on Wordpress known as so called "overlap issue". If you have a CSS styling problem, try to present only the simplified yet related part of your markup (HTML), adding simplified yet related parts of your CSS and remove Wordpress phrases, as this is related to CSS and not Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS (http://quanglepro.com/wp-content/themes/organicfood/framework/shortcodes/shortcodes.css) you need to edit:

```
.readmore {
    border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-shadow: none;
    white-space: normal;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Changing white-space to "normal".

Comment: You seam to have 1K reputation, and I am confused why do you answer such questions on SOF. Please do not answer questions that do not meet SOF standards

Comment: I thought there was enough info in the question and I was able to answer it. I understand your concerns about the quality of the question but it is better than a lot of others I have seen (and flagged). Anyways looks like he doesn't care so wasn't worth my effort anyways.